# Query Posts by Custom Field

Tags: posts, wp-query, custom-field, query-posts

I'm looking to query my posts via a custom field that I've created on my page. But the custom field is an array of values. So the custom field 'country' could look like this

```
country => usa,africa,united kingdom,poland
```

What's confusing me is how to query posts with a custom field which is an array seperated with `',`'?

I've tried quite a few solutions on here with no success.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achive this using [`WP Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) with `meta_query` argument as following.

```
$args = array (
    'post_type'              => array( 'post' ),  // YOUR POST TYPE
    'meta_query'             => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'country',  
            'value'     => $your_country,  // THE COUNTRY TO SEARCH
            'compare'   => 'LIKE',  // TO SEARCH THIS COUNTRY IN YOUR COMMA SEPERATED STRING
            'type'      => 'CHAR',
        ),
    ),
);

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I have tested this query. Working perfect. Hope this might work for you as well.

**Edit:**

For multiple countries you can use following approach.

```
$countries_to_search = 'usa,africa,poland'; // YOUR COMMA SEPARATED STRING
$countries = explode( ',', $countries_to_search ); // CONVERT INTO ARRAY OF COUNTRIES
$meta_array = array();
$meta_array['relation'] = 'AND';  // DECLARE RELATION --> YOU CAN USE 'OR' AS WELL  

foreach($countries as $country){  // CREATE QUERY FOR EACH COUNTRY IN ARRAY

    $meta_array[] =  array(
        'key'       => 'country',  
        'value'     => $country,  // THE COUNTRY TO SEARCH
        'compare'   => 'LIKE',  // TO SEARCH THIS COUNTRY IN YOUR COMMA SEPERATED STRING
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    );

}

$args = array (
        'post_type'     => array( 'post' ),  // YOUR POST TYPE
        'meta_query'    => $meta_array,  // ARRAY CONTAINING META QUERY
        );

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: How would I query by multiple values? e.g. if I want a page to display all posts tagged with 'usa,africa,poland'?

Comment: @Jonathan I have edit my answer for multiple comma separated countries as well.

Comment: Would I be able to store the countries in a custom field within the page then call it? Instead of static values in your edit?

Comment: Sure that's just a variable. You can store any string you want and use it for search. It depends on your usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! How would I set the variable to a custom field within my page?

Comment: You can easily get the value of your `custom field` in page with your `post id` using [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/).